# SQL Update using subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to update a table using a sub query but it's not recognising the table alias, when I try and run it a box pops up with 't1.rDate', my query is:

```
 UPDATE Results SET odds4 = 
(SELECT SUM(IIF(odds >= 4, 1, 0)) FROM Results t1
GROUP BY t1.rDate, t1.rTime, t1.rTrack)
WHERE rDate = t1.rDate AND rTime = t1.rTime AND rTrack = t1.rTrack AND t1.rDate 
>= #2019/05/28#;
```

Example:

```
   rDate   | rTime | rTrack | horse   | odds | odds4
------------------------------------------------------
28/05/2019 | 13:00 | Ascot  | horse1  | 2.5  |  3
28/05/2019 | 13:00 | Ascot  | horse2  | 34   |  3
28/05/2019 | 13:00 | Ascot  | horse3  | 1.4  |  3
28/05/2019 | 13:00 | Ascot  | horse4  | 6    |  3
28/05/2019 | 13:00 | Ascot  | horse5  | 4    |  3
28/05/2019 | 14:30 | Epsom  | horse1  | 3    |  2
28/05/2019 | 14:30 | Epsom  | horse2  | 1.75 |  2
28/05/2019 | 14:30 | Epsom  | horse3  | 2    |  2
28/05/2019 | 14:30 | Epsom  | horse4  | 12   |  2
28/05/2019 | 14:30 | Epsom  | horse5  | 66   |  2
```

Comment: how does this query function when the update statement is removed? - Just run the select

Comment: Yes it functions fine without the update bit, the problem seems to in the last WHERE clause, it's not recognising t1.

Comment: Example provided

Comment: Explain what you want to do. What is your expected result?

Comment: Im trying to count the number of horses in each race that have odds of 4 or above and add that number to the 'odds4' column. A race is a collection of rows that have the same rDate, rTime and rTrack,so I'm grouping by those columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Results
    SET odds4 = (SELECT SUM(IIF(t1.odds >= 4, 1, 0))
                 FROM Results t1
                 WHERE t1.rDate = Results.rDate AND
                       t1.rTime = Results.rTime AND
                       t1.rTrack = Results.rTrack
                )
WHERE Results.rDate >= #2019/05/28#;
```

Comment: I tried running it and it says 'operation must use an updateable query'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Results SET odds4 = 
                 CASE 
                    WHEN odds >= 4 THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                 END 
WHERE rDate >= #2019/05/28#;
```

EDITED CODE :

```
UPDATE Results SET odds4 = (SELECT t1.odds4
 FROM
    (
     SELECT  rDate,
                     rTime,
                     rTrack,
                    SUM(IIF(odds >= 4, 1, 0)) AS odds4
      FROM Results
     GROUP BY rDate, rTime, rTrack
    ) AS t1

  WHERE Results.rDate = t1.rDate
    AND Results.rTime = t1.rTime
    AND Results.rTrack = t1.rTrack
)
    WHERE Results.rDate >= #2019/05/28#;
```

Comment: Im tryng to find how many horses in the race have odds of 4 or above, this query doesn't seem to group by race?

Comment: What is the level of the data? A few column names could help. If you could post what the data looks like now and what you want it to look like, it would be easier to solve.

Comment: The names are in the original post, its just grouping by rDate, rTime, rTrack (i.e each  race) and finding how many rows there are with the 'odds' column above 4, then updating 'odds4' for every row in that race with the result. The select query works I just cant get the update part to work.

Comment: Example provided

Comment: Please try the edited code in the above comment and let me know.

Comment: I get a syntax error, missing operator, and it highlights the FROM on line 2.

Comment: I get the error 'Operation must use an updateable query'. Apparently this is because it uses GROUP BY which makes all the records non-updateable. I'm going to use a temporary table instead to do this, thanks anyway.